# Disable combining and minifying assets in Symfony with Assetic

Tags: symfony, assetic

With the following config, my css and javascript files get to the browser minified and combined, even in dev environment (which is the one I currently use).

How can I have Assetic neither combine nor minify those files in dev environment?

**app/config/config/yml**

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ MyFirstBundle, MySecondBundle, MyThirdBundle ]
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        yui_css:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
        yui_js:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
        less:
            node: %less_node_bin%
            node_paths: [%less_node_modules%]
            apply_to: ".less$"
    assets:
        main_css:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/css/file01.css
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/css/file02.css
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/css/file03.css
            output: css/main.css
            filter:
                - yui_css
                - less
        other_css:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/css/file04.css
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/css/file05.css
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../web/css/file06.css
            output: css/other.css
            filter:
                - yui_css
                - less
        other_js:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../src/My/FirstBundle/Resources/public/js/file01.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../src/My/FirstBundle/Resources/public/js/file02.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../src/My/FirstBundle/Resources/public/js/file03.js
            output: js/other.js
            filter:
                - yui_js
        main_js:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../src/My/FirstBundle/Resources/public/js/file01.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../src/My/FirstBundle/Resources/public/js/file02.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../src/My/FirstBundle/Resources/public/js/file03.js
            output: js/main.js
            filter:
                - yui_js
```

**app/config/config_dev.yml**

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: true
    bundles:        [ MyFirstBundle, MySecondBundle, MyThirdBundle ]
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        yui_css:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
        yui_js:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
    assets:
```

**twig template:**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My title</title>
    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}">
    {% endblock %}
    {% block javascripts %}
        <script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
    <!--
    Also tried this type of block, without success:
    {% block javascripts %}
        {% javascripts '@main_js' %}
            <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}
    {% endblock %}
    -->
</head>
```

Comment: It is described in the documentation... http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/assetic/yuicompressor.html#disable-minification-in-debug-mode

Comment: I read the doc and can't get it to work. Can you propose an answer?

Comment: What I have tried so far is what you can see in my question. It's the best I have been able to come up with. I won't paste here the hundreds of changes I have tried on each line, one by one. I know "it is documented", but it doesn't help me solve my problem. And I also know I'm doing something wrong, this is not a bug report...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is "config.yml" file is **always** used in **all** environments. For example, in the dev enviroment "config.yml" and "config_dev.yml" files are merged to form the final config.

For example we have **config.yml** file with this:

```
foo:
    bar: baz
```

And we have **config_dev.yml** with something like this:

```
foo:
    go: run
```

The final config will have

```
foo:
    bar: baz
    go: run
```

You see the problem? Yo need to place **prod** specific configuration parameters (that you wish to use only in prod environment, like js minifiers in your case) not in the **config.yml** file, but in the **config_prod.yml** file.

So you should have something like this in your **config.yml**:

```
assetic:
    assets:
        my_js_asset:
            inputs:
                ...
```

And something like this in your **config_prod.yml** file

```
assetic:
    assets:
        my_js_asset:
            filters: [yui_js]
            output:  scripts.min.js
```

### EDIT 1:

However, this will fix only the minification (and other possible filters) issue.

Maybe I'm wrong, but, as far as I know, right now it is not possible to separate various input files defined within the same named asset. The logic behind this lies in the assetic implementation of the corresponding twig tags (nodes), because the separate files them self **are generated** and can be found in the target directory after executing assetic:dump command in the dev environment (Or if the stylesheets\javascripts twig tag`s parameter "combine" attribute is set to true). If you want to inspect this and better understand the implementation, this is a good starting point: https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/blob/master/src/Assetic/Extension/Twig/AsseticNode.php

Comment: I still get a combined file. What has changed is it's not minified anymore and the html tag src attribute is different (e.g.: `/css/49e9dec_part_1.css` for `@main_css`). In case it can help, here's how I applied your suggestion: http://pastebin.com/aLtnyLff

Comment: As far as I know, when using so called named assets (assets defined explicitly in the config file) they will always be combined (I mean several inputs defined under the one named asset definition will be combined). The only way to make named assets separate is to put each file in a separate named asset.

Comment: This has crossed my mind too, but only because I can't find other reasons. I would gladly accept it as an answer, though, if I could be a bit more sure *this* is the problem (some doc, article, source code, etc., which I have been unable to find until today...)

Comment: No better answer than your comment has been proposed yet. Could you edit your answer in this line  (i.e. it's impossible with named assets) so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

- You don't need to override all the config in `config_dev.yml`, just override the `use_controller` option is enough.
- In your template, use the commented one. The current one will use the dumped asset, so if you already dump them minified, it will be always used, it will never use the Assetic controller.
- In `config.yml`, as the doc says, you should use `- ?yui_css` instead of `- yui_css`, note the leading question mark (same with `yui_js`). Then these filters will not be used in debug mode (in dev env)

Comment: I've just tried (again) your three suggestions and cleared Symfony's cache, just in case. I still get only one minified resource per named asset, only the name of the resource has changed. For instance instead of `/js/main.js`, my script tag's `src` is now `/js/222fa77_part_1.js`

Comment: What happened if you completly remove `yui_css`/`yui_js` filters in your config?

Comment: Sorry, when I said "*I still get only one minified resource per named asset*" I meant "*only one **combined** resource*". It is indeed not minified. If I remove completely `yui_css`/`yui_js`, I get the same result, combined but not minified.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to simplify the config.yml as follows:

```
assetic:
debug:          %kernel.debug%
use_controller: %kernel.debug%
bundles:        [ MyFirstBundle, MySecondBundle, MyThirdBundle ]
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    yui_css:
        jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
    yui_js:
        jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
    less:
        node: %less_node_bin%
        node_paths: [%less_node_modules%]
        apply_to: ".less$"
```

And then, configure the CSS and JS files in the layout template itself:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My title</title>

    {% stylesheets 'css/file01.css' 'css/file02.css' 'css/file03.css'
        filter='?yui_css, less' output='css/main.css' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}

    {% stylesheets 'css/file04.css' 'css/file05.css' 'css/file06.css'
        filter='?yui_css, less' output='css/other.css' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}

    {% javascripts
        '@FirstBundle/Resources/public/js/thirdparty/file01.js'
        '@FirstBundle/Resources/public/js/thirdparty/file02.js'
        '@FirstBundle/Resources/public/js/thirdparty/file03.js'
        filter='?yui_js' output='js/other.js' %}
         <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}

    {% javascripts
        '@FirstBundle/Resources/public/js/thirdparty/file04.js'
        '@FirstBundle/Resources/public/js/thirdparty/file05.js'
        '@FirstBundle/Resources/public/js/thirdparty/file06.js'
        filter='?yui_js' output='js/main.js' %}
         <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
</head>
```